# Vault error while writing

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I wanted to test Spring Cloud Vault configuration.

I installed a Vault server locally and when i try to `write` some key-values its failing and asking me to use `vault kv put` command.

While the example of Spring Cloud Config [in this link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/24/managing-secrets-with-vault) shows the usage of vault write command

This is the error i get is

```
$ vault write secret/my-app foo=bar
Error writing data to secret/my-app: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/my-app
Code: 404. Errors:


WARNING! The following warnings were returned from Vault:

  * Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for the
  appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use 'vault kv put'
  for this operation.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to write after enabling a separate path with the below command

```
vault secrets enable -path=my-app kv
vault write my-app/my-app password=123
```

In Spring Cloud Config, i had to mention the folder name as backend in `bootstrap.yml` file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      token: bc53d1a4-2551-4869-9574-7a9e60501ec1
      scheme: http
      generic:
        backend: my-app
```

Answer (score 25):

Try the following ..

```
./vault kv put secret/my-app password=123
```

I'll add that this is something new in 0.10.0.

Seems like 0.10.0 has some breaking API changes ... so solution #2 is to use an earlier version of Vault (v0.9.6).  This includes defaulting to the v2 of the KV secret engine , which is versioned.

Solution #3 is to re-create the /secret engine with v1 of KV. Running the following:

```
./vault secrets disable secret 
./vault secrets enable -version=1 -path=secret kv
```

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you. This answer, in addition to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/380 put me on the right track. Ah, frameworks....

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, during using python, hvac,  vault and kv as engine. And kv-engine is versioned. I used hvac client

```
client.write("secret/taras", data=dict(python='is secret'))
```

So I got

> InvalidPath: "request_id":"d5c0f889-2c42-4141-1cc6-31ed1336c768","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":null,"wrap_info":null,"warnings":["Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for the appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use 'vault kv put' for this operation."],"auth":null}

The way I have solved this issue was changing path for storing secret

```
client.write("secret/data/taras", data=dict(python='is secret'))
```

PS: as you understood the name of my secret is "taras".

Comment: Thanks for this, I had no idea the "data" had to be added to the path!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in windows , (in command prompt) ,

SET VAULT_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

SET VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200

vault kv put secret/gs-vault-config example.username=demouser example.password=demopassword

(There is change in creating key-value in Hashicorp Vault now. Use kv put instead of write.)