# Spring Vault VaultTemplate.read() returns null

Tags: java, spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have a Vault server running:

```
$ vault server --dev --dev-root-token-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
$ export VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

The Spring artifact has the `spring-cloud-starter-vault-config` maven dependency.
When using VaultTemplate, it writes and reads secrets without problem using the following methods:

```
VaultKeyValueOperations keyValue = vaultOperations
                    .opsForKeyValue("secret", VaultKeyValueOperationsSupport.KeyValueBackend.versioned());
            keyValue.put("myPath", mySecretsObject);
```

and

```
VaultResponse response = vaultOperations
                    .opsForKeyValue("secret", VaultKeyValueOperationsSupport.KeyValueBackend.KV_2).get("myPath");
```

But, if I use `write` and `read` methods it throws errors:

```
vaultOperations.write("secret/myPath", mySecretsObject);
```

returns

> {
>       "timestamp": "2019-11-19T18:22:52.156+0000",
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "message": "Status 404 Not Found [secret/myPath]: {\"request_id\":\"23062c09-f9cf-f170-930c-e6d60f98dd62\",\"lease_id\":\"\",\"renewable\":false,\"lease_duration\":0,\"data\":null,\"wrap_info\":null,\"warnings\":[\"Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for the
>   appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use 'vault
>   kv put' for this operation.\"],\"auth\":null}; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404
>   Not Found",
>       "path": "/vault/secrets/mySecrets" }

And for

```
VaultResponse response= vaultOperations.read("secret/" + environment);
            String stringResp = response.getData().toString();
```

`response` is null. There is no error for the read, but I get `NullPointerException` when trying to read `response`, as it is empty.

I have found a question related to the write error -[Vault error while writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872480/vault-error-while-writing) - but it's in the context of the Vault CLI. Can't find how to apply the solution in a Spring environment.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Vault adds the data/ context between the mount path and the actual context path, have look:
[How to read Vault kv with java/spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100532/how-to-read-vault-kv-with-java-spring-boot)

Try:
"secret/data/myPath" where secrets is your Secret engine type kv

Comment: @chomarc.c - I did try adding `data` but it does not work.